# Разделить тысячные на php

Tags: php

Есть задача сделать из 1000 вот это 1 000 или например будет не 1000, а 10000 то надо так же сделать 10 000. Как на php это реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для форматирования с разделителями используйте [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с опережающей и ретроспективной проверкой

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)~', ' ', '10000');
```

Answer (score -3):

Лол:

```
strrev( implode( ' ', str_split( strrev( $value ), 3 ) ) );
```

Comment: Не используйте в этом форуме фразы насмешек  - это проявление неуважения к задающему вопрос

Comment: @Mcile Не вижу насмешки. А решение забавное. Думаю, потому и `:lol:`